# ->fetch returns all fields as string

Tags: cakephp

Even in `src/Database/StatementInterface.php` the functions `fetch` and `fetchAll` have these comment:

```
  $statement = $connection->prepare('SELECT id, title from articles');
  $statement->execute();
  print_r($statement->fetchAll('assoc')); // will show [0 => ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'a title']]
```

the functions return **ALL** fields as `string`, even the fields are defined as numeric:

```
  array(4) {
    ["lat"]=>
    string(11) "38.49580000"
    ["lng"]=>
    string(11) "-6.95301000"
    ["taken_at"]=>
    string(19) "2021-03-30 16:24:30"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1
```

The fields `lat` and `lng` are defined as `DECIMAL(10,8)|(11,8)` and `id` is `INTEGER`. CakePHP 4.3.1 [and also former versions] return the fields as `string` which breaks the code.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the lowest level of database operations that CakePHP provides, this is almost directly operating with PDO, no casting by CakePHP will apply here, and what exactly you'll receive will entirely depend on the DBMS and the PDO driver that you're using.

Most drivers will return everything as a string, others do cast some values, for example with Postgres you can get integers, while with MySQL you'll get everything as strings.

Comment: Thank you ndm for your clarification. Maybe the CakePHP team can add your note into the documentation as it's really confusing - when you don't know this detail.

Comment: @PeterVARGA If you create an issue over at GitHub, someone might take up the task :)